# Android app widget too big although used formula

Tags: android, android-appwidget

Users of my Android app report that the included app widget is too big.

I've used this formula:

```
width/height = (number-of-cells * 74) - 2
```

So I got 294dp width and 72dp height for a 4x1 widget. But, as I've said, users report that the widget takes more place than 4x1.

How can this happen? Does it differ with different Android versions?

**Edit:** I've set this as the minimum width/height and the resize width/height. My layout file for this appwidget uses `fill_parent` so it should not extend that size.

Comment: Do you have some screen shot ? OR ask users to have screen shot. Maybe user want only some padding inside your layout. I use 
android:minWidth="294dip"
android:minHeight="72dip" 
And it's perfect on android 2.1 to android 4.2 :)

Comment: Yes, these are the values that I was using, too. But for Android 4.0+, they're definitely incorrect. See the formula given in the docs (link in raina77ow's answer). Maybe you haven't set the target SDK level to 14+, could this be true? Perhaps this causes your values to still work on Android 4?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This documentation page](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html#anatomy_determining_size) (relevant for Android 4.x, I suppose) shows that the formula is:

```
width/height = `70 * n - 30`
```

... where `n` is the number of cells taken. It also mentions that...

> When your widget is added, it will be stretched to occupy the minimum
>   number of cells, horizontally and vertically, required to satisfy its
>   minWidth and minHeight constraints

Based on the dimensions given in the question, your application would stretch to 5 cells (320dp; 250dp is not enough) width-wise and 2 cells (110dp; 40dp is not enough) height-wise.

Comment: Thanks! Is this new, for Android 4.0+? I'm sure it were my values for earlier versions, could this be true? So if my app must cover Android 2.2 to Android 4.1, which sizes do I rely on?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but it looks like the formula has changed in Android 4.0 (I made a quick glance through Wayback Machine, it seems to confirm this suggestion; the formula was the one you've show at Android 3.1 version of that page).

Comment: Thanks a lot! You see, this makes everything quite difficult. Does anybody know which values to use if the app covers not only Android 4.0? This should be a question which many developers have to face, as most apps support Android 2, or at least Android 3, as well.

Answer (score 4):

To support different widgets for different Android versions is quite simple.

For supporting Android version >= 4.0, you have to put your widgets stuff in the right folder.

- `/res/xml-v14`
- `/res/layout-v14` [optional]

`-v14` means the API-Level 14 (Android 4.0). Android version higher or equals 4.0 will use the files in these folders. Don't forget to calculate `android:minWidth` and `android:minHeight` using the correct formula:

```
cell_size in dp = 70 × n − 30
```

You can leave your working widget in the existing folders:

- `/res/xml`
- `/res/layout`

Using the correct forumla:

```
cell_size in dp = 74 × n - 2
```

To keep it simple and reuse the calculated dimensions you can also create the correct dimensions in the correct folder and reference to the size.

- Create a file `/res/values/widget_size.xml` containing the dimensions for Android version < 4.0

> ```
> <resources>
>     <dimen name="cell_size_1">72dp</dimen>
>     <dimen name="cell_size_2">146dp</dimen> 
> </resources>
> ```

- Create a file `/res/values-v14/widget_size.xml` containing the dimensions for Android version >= 4.0

> ```
> <resources>
>     <dimen name="cell_size_1">40dp</dimen>
>     <dimen name="cell_size_2">110dp</dimen>
> </resources>
> ```

- Reference the size of the widget to the new created dimensions.

> ```
> android:minWidth="@dimen/cell_size_2"
> android:minHeight="@dimen/cell_size_1"
> ```

Unfortunately this does not work on my Galaxy Tab 7.7 running Android 4.04. A 3x1 widget is 2x1, although it shows the correct size on the emulator. I assume it is because of

> While the width and height of a cell—as well as the amount of
>   automatic margins applied to widgets—may vary across devices, you can
>   use the table below to **roughly estimate** your widget's minimum
>   dimensions, given the desired number of occupied grid cells:

stated at [App Widget Design Guidelines](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html)

Comment: Thank you! Another possibility is to have one common XML and layout folder and only put the dimensions in version-specific folders. By the way, I have a Samsung device which shows widgets as 3x1 instead of 4x1 as well.

Comment: That seems to be a quite simpler solution (will update my answer). Are you running the (original) Samsungs Android version? Maybe this is a Samsung specific problem.

Comment: Yes, I own the Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 10.1 and I'm running the stock software. Could be Samsung-specific, yes.

Comment: Ive got same issues on other devices. Nexus 7 for example.